# Calculate shipping after WC fees API

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The current order of the cart totals calculation of Woocommerce is:

1. Subtotal
2. Shipping
3. **Fees API** (`add_fee`)

I'd like to change this so shipping is calculated **AFTER** the fees:

1. Subtotal
2. **Fees API** (`add_fee`)
3. Shipping

I'm using the `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` action to add a discount percentage of specific cart items.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/add-a-surcharge-to-cart-and-checkout-uses-fees-api/